# Xfreerdp Upgrade to version 1.1 to support Multi Monitor

Tags: upgrade, multiple-monitors

I was trying to use freerdp with support for multiple monitor using ubuntu 13.10 x64 and I get error :

```
root@rdp-client:~# xfreerdp /multimon /f /u:a /p:1 /v:192.168.0.140:3389
transport_connect: getaddrinfo (Name or service not known)
Error:protocol security negotition failure
```

my version of freerdp 1.0.2

How can I upgrade to xfreerdp version 1.1 to support this syntax of command and multi monitor?

Comment: Have you managed to sort out this problem? Stuck with the same error here :/

Answer (score 0):

FreeRDP has been above version 1.1 since Vivid - so the easiest way to get a compatible version is now to just install a recent version of Ubuntu. That said, Windows still imposes restrictions on which editions support multi monitor on the server.

There are *no* versions of Windows that support multimon on a *Home* edition server (the computer you're connecting **to**).

Windows 7 only supports it on *Ultimate* and *Enterprise* editions and **not** *Pro*.

Windows 8 and 10 support it on *Pro* and *Enterprise* editions (and there is no *Ultimate* edition).

Old answer preserved below.

---

The easiest means of getting a version of FreeRDP that supports multimon seems to be via this PPA :

https://launchpad.net/~9v-shaun-42/+archive/freerdp

(the usual warnings about using a PPA for software apply).

That said... I tried this and still no joy. Why?

I'm running Windows 7 Professional on the server machine I want to use. Which doesn't support multimon as a server, just as a client. So FreeRDP enters span mode anyway, which is not what I need because my monitors have different vertical resolutions.

This is by design, apparently. Multimon RDP *service* is only supported by Windows 7 Ultimate or Enterprise, even if the RDP client on other editions supports using it.  [1]

I can't imagine the number of hours of productivity that have been lost by people trying to get this to work and finally discovering it's not supported on their edition of Windows.....

[1] http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/75f72cb1-fa8b-46bd-ad95-8a8d22042db0/multimonitor-on-windows-7-professional-running-rdp?forum=w7itproperf

Comment: I think this PPA is gone.

Comment: It should be redundant now - freerdp has been version 1.1 since Vivid, so the latest LTS release of Ubuntu has a freerdp package compatible with -multimon ; that said, limitations still apply to which versions of Windows support multimon on the *server* ;  Window 7 ; Ultimate and Enterprise ; Windows 8 and 10 - Pro and Enterprise. ie - "Home" edition does not support multimon as a server for ANY version of Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is installing from source files : take a look at https://github.com/FreeRDP/FreeRDP/wiki/Compilation

But as it mentioned by Adrian check the server support for multimonitor before it :D

Comment: While the information in the link may answer the question you should include the detail in your answer should the link ever go dead.